# Java - prevent browser from re-localizing localized date

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, jodatime

In our database, we have a column which contains the local date/time of the db (in this case it is US/Pacific).

In our service, our DAO model stores it as a java.util.Date object.  Our service layer model stores it as a DateTime object.  Here is an example

Database: 2014-04-20 23:22:27

```
Date date = daoModel.getDate();
System.out.println(Date.toString()); // Wed Apr 30 23:22:27 PDT 2014 (Correct)

// converting to service layer which clients will get
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString()); // 2014-04-30T23:22:27.000-07:00 (I am running this on a JRE that is in US/Pacific)
```

Then in javascript, we do this with the string from the DateTime object:

```
        var formatDate = function(dateString){
            if(dateString){
                var date = new Date(Date.parse(dateString.trim()));
                return twoDigits(date.getFullYear())+"-"+
                        twoDigits(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+
                        twoDigits(date.getDate())+" "+
                        twoDigits(date.getHours())+":"+
                        twoDigits(date.getMinutes())+":"+
                        twoDigits(date.getSeconds());
            }
            return "";

        }
```

And the output in a browser located in US/Pacific is: 2014-04-30 16:22:27
So it has subtracted another 7 hours off of the already localized time.

So for the date string 2014-04-30T23:22:27.000-07:00, does the DateTime class assume that 2014-04-30T23:22:27.000 is UTC and the -07:00 is the offset to get local time, or does it assume that 2014-04-30T23:22:27.000 is actually local time, and -07:00 just indicates the timezone offset from UTC?

My desired output in the browser is the local date that is stored in the database, so it would be

```
2014-04-30 23:22:27
```

But the current output is

```
2014-04-30 16:22:27
```

I am trying to understand why, by the time it's displayed in the browser, the offset is -14:00 from UTC instead of -7 for US/Pacific, and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you have an [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) timestamp containing an offset, such as the value you asked about, `"2014-04-30T23:22:27.000-07:00"`, the time represents the *local* time, and the offset represents adjustment from UTC that is represented by that local time.

To get back to UTC, you would invert the sign of the offset, and apply it to the local time value.

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to the rest of your question.  In the title, you appear to be asking a question about JavaScript in the browser, but you provide no supporting details.  In the question body you make lot of statements about Java without asking a question.  Then finally at the end you ask a question about the nature of ISO timestamps, which aren't language dependent at all.  I'd be happy to help further, after you've edited your question to make clearer what you are asking.

Comment: So the client is somehow getting that date and 'localizing' it to 2014-04-30 16:22:27, which has basically double-localized it offsetting 14 hours from UTC instead of 7.  It's still not clear to me how this is happening.

*edit*

Saw your comment right after this - I have edited my original question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: What browser?  Not all browsers can fully parse ISO8601.  You may need to parse it manually, or use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) (recommended).

Comment: The browser is Firefox

Comment: Latest version? Or old?

Comment: RE the edit - If ultimately your question is about javascript, please remove all the bits about java and jodatime, and edit the title and tags accordingly.  That just confuses the issue.

Comment: The latest version of Firefox.  And I put both in because I'm not quite sure where the error is occurring.  I'd like to fix it in the java code if I can.

Comment: You need to tell us which area the problem is in.  We can't debug your entire code base.  Are you actually passing the full ISO string with-offset that you specified? Or perhaps you're passing something else.  Open FireFox's dev console and try `new Date(Date.parse("2014-04-30T23:22:27.000-07:00"))` there.  I think you'll find it parses correctly.

Comment: It looks like the string we are parsing in the javascript is 2014-04-30T23:22:27.000Z, which if I'm not mistaken indicates Zulu (UTC), which would explain why it's being localied to 16h instead of 23h. Let me find where this is being generated.

Comment: Yes, that would explain it.